# How to change update statements into insert statements while maintaining SET command from UPDATE command?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

As the title suggests, I need to change my update and join statements into insert statements. How I would do this while incorporating `SET` from the `UPDATE` statements?

Update statement:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET    A = tableB.A
FROM   tableB
JOIN   tableC ON tableB.C = tableC.C
WHERE  tableC.D = tableA.D
```

Comment: Why do you need this? How is this supposed to work? This seems to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide details.

Comment: I need to convert my update statements into insert statements because the tables that I need to insert into have been wiped clean. I tried running the update statement as is, but it updated zero rows and I was told to make it into insert statements. Hope this helps.

Comment: "wiped clean" is not the correct SQL parlance ... If the record exists: you could update it, if not: you'll need to insert it. No sigar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables are empty, thus `tableC.D = tableA.D` wouldn't provide anything.

May it be you are looking for something like this?:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (A)
SELECT DISTINCT tb.A
FROM tableB tb
JOIN tableC tc ON tb.C = tc.C
```

Or perhaps including the `D` column:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (A, D)
SELECT DISTINCT tb.A, tc.D
FROM tableB tb
JOIN tableC tc ON tb.C = tc.C
```

Note the use of `DISTINCT` here to dispense duplicate records.

Comment: my only concern is how will the SET from my post fit into your insert statement?

Comment: SET is not a valid syntax for INSERT. This is done in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is good practice to include all the column names in the INSERT statement. And you can remove WHERE clause by JOINing tableA to tableC. But just the simple answer for your question would be:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (<col name you want to update>)
VALUES (SELECT <one value> FROM tableB JOIN tableC ON  tableB.C = tableC.C JOIN tableA ON tableC.D = tableA.D
);
```

Comment: my only concern is how will the SET from my post fit into your insert statement?

Comment: As far as I know you don't use SET inside INSERT statement